# Suspicious Text Message Received

Tags: sms

I received an html text message from a `Leah_Condello` where I could not click `MORE` except to delete it, but I don't know anyone with that name and the code made me wonder if this is a new virus attempt, especially since I can't see the details of where's it's from (like an email address, phone, or any other information).  Plus, how is it possible that the person was able to send a text message with their name when this name isn't in my contacts at all?

This person was able to send information without details and have their name added to my contacts.  How is this possible, or is this something dangerous, and what should I do?

Comment: Are you using Hangouts for everything? I used to get these once in a while, they actually were not text messages, but Hangouts messages. Also, "text" messages are SMS and would be plain text only, not HTML, for it to be HTML it would have to be an MMS message, which has a some extra stuff allowed. Personally, if it is a one time thing, I would just delete it and go about my normal life, I get junk messages from time to time.

Comment: I just got this too. Mms, didn't open it though. Don't know any body by that name. Got it about 20 minutes ago, same name.

Comment: OP, please register your account and follow http://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to regain control of this post, so that you can leave comments and edit freely.

Comment: They are saying that stagefright is back.....